# Codeigniter Email keep saying Invalid Characters

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I'm encountering these issues on my Codeigniter project and I do always receive below statement in my email

> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
> may not support this format. --B_ALT_65a00686dc208 Content-Type:
> text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit click on
> this link to delete your Account --B_ALT_65a00686dc208 Content-Type:
> text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> click on this link to delete your Account --B_ALT_65a00686dc208--

**Here is my code**

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'ssmtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_timeout' => '7',
        'smtp_user' => $get_site_g_name,
        'smtp_pass' => $get_site_g_pass,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'newline' => "\r\n",
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'validation' => FALSE
    ); // bool whether to validate email or not
    
    $this->load->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    $this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


    $current_domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $this->email->from('info@' . $current_domain, $get_site_name);
    $this->email->to($dis_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);

    $data['message'] = $message;
    $data['title'] = 'Thank You';
    $data['link_title'] = $link_title;
    $data['link'] = $link;
    
    $this->email->message($message);
```

Email is sent out to Email, but the content in the email it's not readable for users.
please how do I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Try and set the newline/crlf character as `"\n"` only, and see if that helps. (Inside the mail it needs to be `\r\n`, but some MTAs manipulate the line breaks on their own, so that if you pass `\r\n` to start with, the end result will be messed up.)

Comment: oooh okay, I will try that out now.
thanks for contributing